# Conditional reverse proxy based on host url in apache

Tags: apache-2.4, apache2

I have two websites deployed in apache in two ports 81 and 82

```
<VirtualHost *:81>
    DocumentRoot "D:/WebApps/App1"
    ServerName localhost
    <Directory "D:/WebApps/App1">
        Require all granted
    </Directory>        
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:82>
    DocumentRoot "D:/WebApps/App2"
    ServerName localhost
    <Directory "D:/WebApps/App2">
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I have made two DNS entries as follows

```
app1.domain.com <server ip>
app2.domain.com <server ip>
```

I want to configure Reverse Proxy on port `80` so that requests made with `app1.domain.com` gets proxied to port `81` and requests made with `app2.domain.com` gets proxied to port `82`

What I have tried so far is -

```
<VirtualHost app1.domain.com:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off
    ServerName app1.domain.com
    ServerAlias app2.domain.com
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:81/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:81/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost app2.domain.com:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off
    ServerName app1.domain.com
    ServerAlias app2.domain.com
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:82/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:82/
</VirtualHost>
```

But request with both domains are getting sent to port 81. Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: The ServerName and Server Allias are wrong.  Make ServerName the same as the VirtualHost in each block, delete the ServerAlias (for now) and reload and try again.  https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#serveralias

Comment: the current settings worked, ran `httpd -S` and found that for some reason the server was unable to resolve `app2.domain.com`. so I made an entry of it in the servers hosts file and now its working.